# I get errors in debug/AndroidManifest.xml when I have not touched it at all

Tags: java, android, xml, android-manifest

To be honest I do not know how and why it happened. I was just programming normally when it randomly happened. I have not touched that file or anyhting, so what can it be? It lierally just happened randomly, I do not know what to do.
Maybe something in the normal Android Manifest made it happen.

debug/AndroidManifest.xml

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="co.quindio.sena.navigationdrawerejemplo"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="15"
        android:targetSdkVersion="25" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <!--
         The ACCESS_COARSE/FINE_LOCATION permissions are not required to use
         Google Maps Android API v2, but you must specify either coarse or fine
         location permissions for the 'MyLocation' functionality. 
    -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

    <meta-data
        android:name="android.support.VERSION"
        android:value="25.3.1" /> <!-- Include required permissions for Google Maps API to run. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:debuggable="true"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="false"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:largeHeap="true"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="co.quindio.sena.navigationdrawerejemplo.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
        <activity android:name="co.quindio.sena.navigationdrawerejemplo.Publicacion" />
        <activity android:name="co.quindio.sena.navigationdrawerejemplo.Gallery" />
        <activity android:name="co.quindio.sena.navigationdrawerejemplo.fragments.Prueba" />
        <activity android:name="co.quindio.sena.navigationdrawerejemplo.LoginActivity" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="co.quindio.sena.navigationdrawerejemplo.RegisterActivity" />
        <activity android:name="co.quindio.sena.navigationdrawerejemplo.Main2Activity" />
        <!--
             The API key for Google Maps-based APIs is defined as a string resource.
             (See the file "res/values/google_maps_api.xml").
             Note that the API key is linked to the encryption key used to sign the APK.
             You need a different API key for each encryption key, including the release key that is used to
             sign the APK for publishing.
             You can define the keys for the debug and release targets in src/debug/ and src/release/. 
        -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />

        <activity
            android:name="co.quindio.sena.navigationdrawerejemplo.MapsActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_maps" />
        <activity
            android:name="co.quindio.sena.navigationdrawerejemplo.MapsActivity2"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_maps2" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiActivity"
            android:exported="false"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" />

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.VERSION"
            android:value="26.1.0" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.arch.lifecycle.VERSION"
            android:value="27.0.0-SNAPSHOT" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Normal AndroidManifest.xml

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="co.quindio.sena.navigationdrawerejemplo">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />


    <!--
         The ACCESS_COARSE/FINE_LOCATION permissions are not required to use
         Google Maps Android API v2, but you must specify either coarse or fine
         location permissions for the 'MyLocation' functionality. 
    -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="false"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:largeHeap="true"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
        <activity android:name=".Publicacion" />
        <activity android:name=".Gallery" />
        <activity android:name=".fragments.Prueba" />
        <activity android:name=".LoginActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".RegisterActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".Main2Activity" />
        <!--
             The API key for Google Maps-based APIs is defined as a string resource.
             (See the file "res/values/google_maps_api.xml").
             Note that the API key is linked to the encryption key used to sign the APK.
             You need a different API key for each encryption key, including the release key that is used to
             sign the APK for publishing.
             You can define the keys for the debug and release targets in src/debug/ and src/release/. 
        -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />

        <activity
            android:name=".MapsActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_maps" />
        <activity
            android:name=".MapsActivity2"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_maps2"></activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please be more specific:

- Where are the bugs in the compiled `AndroidManifest.xml`?
- What does the `Build Output` log say?

Did you already try:

- `Clean Project` / `Rebuild Project`
- Check if all `Acitivities` in the `AndroidManfiest.xml` exist